# Set Apache to allow access for a directory not under document root

Tags: apache

My only virtual host in Apache has /var/www/html as its document root, that html is a symbolic link to something like /home/yanzs/web/some-project/. I am doing this so that I can easily work on a new web project without create a new virtual host in apache. So here is my problem, when I access localhost, it says

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

How can I set permissions for that "/home/yanzs/web/some-project/" directory, or better its parent directory "/home/yanzs/web/"?

Here is the default setting for /var/www/ directory, does the FollowSymLinks option automatically set permissions for directories that are the targets of symbolinks under /var/www?

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Update**: I also tried to use the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) setting, does not work either.
**Update 2**: If I set the document root as /var/www/html, and create a symbolic link under html directory, pointing to /var/www/project. Then it works, and the Alias method works too.  It seems that it has something todo with the owner or other file permission settings. All files and folders under /var/www are owned by root, while those under /home/yanzs/web are owned by yanzs.

**Solution:**

It turns out that permission on **all** parent directories matters, too. One of the parent directory is copied from Windows and does not have the required permission by default. See [(13) Permission Denied](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) for more details. One lesson learned is never forget to check the error logs, even if you know permissions are relevant from output of browser.

Comment: Does your "/home/yanzs/web/some-project/" dir have an index.html file? I see this problem if there are no default homepage files (index.htm, .html, .php etc).

Comment: @jammypeach Yes, there is the index.html file. And check my "Update 2"  for more information, thanks for your time

Comment: reading that, I'd agree about permissions. Try adding apache's user (www or httpd or apache, whichever applies) to your group, and granting group read write and execute permissions on your symlinked directory. That will probably do it (you may need to reload apache too).

Comment: @jammypeach my apaches seems to be run by a user named www-data, I add that user to my group but it still not working. I even "chown -R root project" and "chmod 777 -R project" so that the project folder has same  user, group, and permission setting as that of /var/www/html, but problem stay.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you could try in that case - sorry but I don't have any more suggestions. Maybe some more googling could help, or someone who knows more will be able to answer on here.

Comment: Thanks, @jammypeach. I figured it out at last. I checked the error log to see if there is more info there, and found "access denied because search permissions are missing on a component of the path". Googling that leads me to [(13) Permission Denied](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied), and found that one of the parent directories (the project path is deeper than I described here) have permision 700. Access to user directories shouldn't be a problem since apache docs memtion such usage without mush explanations. But my direcotry is copied from windows, and has 700 mode by default

Comment: Please take a look at [this link about chmod operation on symbolic link][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/303040/how-do-file-permissions-apply-to-symlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that **permission on all parent directories matters**, too. One of the parent directory is copied from Windows and does not have the required permission by default. See [(13) Permission Denied](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) for more details. One lesson learned is never forget to check the error logs, even if you know permissions are relevant from output of browser.